# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:354))

Tags: flutter, dart, https

I am trying to make a GET request to openweathermap API using http package in flutter,
This is my code

```
void getData() async{
    http.Response response = await http.get('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=36&lon=140&appid={API%20key}');
    print(response.statusCode);
 }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold(
    );
 }
```

But I am getting this exception when I run it in an Android device.

**Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:354))**

I have checked the URI in POSTMAN it works fine.
I tried the solutions available out there but nothing works for me. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Once I used http instead of https it worked!

Answer (score 0):

best way for ssl certification problem on all http requests

it is work on both platform (android & ios)

```
 class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> host=="www.myHost.com";
  }
}

void main(){
    HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
    runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: This is bad advice.
Essentially, you silently turn off all security when accessing the internet, opening the app to all imaginable attack vectors.
If you MUST trust a self-signed certificate and can not install it on the device, you should be selective and ONLY accept this one self-signed token.